# How to make md-sidenav to have full height with ui-router?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I'm using latest **Angular Material (1.0.0)** library and I'm trying to have `<md-sidebar>` panel to have full height of available space on the page.
As soon as it's being used on a normal page (without ui-router) everything works fine but as soon as `ui-router` is used the sidebar is not stretched for full length but takes only space needed to cover it's elements.
Looks like the problem is caused by `<ui-view>` element that is added by `ui-router`. As soon as I manually remove this tag the sidebar is well stretched for full length.
I've already tried to use recommendations from **previous versions** of Angular Material library:

1. Set `height: 100%` for `.ng-scope` class
2. Add `flex` and `layout-fill` classes to `<ui-view>` element

Nothing of this works. How can we make sidebar to have full available height?

I've created Plunker to demonstrate the [issue](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZkgyzZSKfyePqZALevAz?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added style .ng-scope as 100% in style and it worked for me.

```
.ng-scope{
  height: 100%;
}
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YlcUymTOqzKodRXuMZEd?p=preview)

Comment: This is an epic fail... Looks like I've tried solution with `height: 100%` and it didn't work. After that I've reverted height value and added `layout-fill` to starting `<div>` but didn't try to add again `height:100%`. This is true that solution works as soon as **both** of recommendations are used **together**. Thank you @Cyril.